# SharedPreferences lost on force quit?

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I've added the SharedPreferences functionality to my App to launch a specific activity once the App starts after it has been quited.

I use the following code to save the string:

```
final SharedPreferences pref1 = getSharedPreferences("myapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref1.edit();
            editor.putString("Stringval", "view1");
            editor.commit();
```

Then the following to load the last used activity, this code is below `OnCreate`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final SharedPreferences pref1 = getSharedPreferences("myapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String str1= pref1.getString("Stringval", null);

        if(str1 == "view0")
        {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view0);
        }

        else if(str1 == "view1")
        {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view1);
        }
        else
        {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_no_setup);
        }

    }
```

The code works if the user just quits the App, then relaunches it (Only tested it in the Simulator so far) but whenever I use the task manager to force quit the app like this:
[image: forcequit]
The App just relaunches without using the `SharedPreferences`.
What's the reason for the App to not load the `SharedPreferences` or is this just a simulator bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write

```
if(str1 != null && str1.equals("view0"))
        {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view0);
        }

        else if(str1 != null && str1.equals("view1"))
        {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view1);
        }
        else
        {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_no_setup);
        }
```

try this, May be helpful for you......